StatusTip of a QStandard item not showing up in the Qstatusbar
I have an application with a Qstatusbar and a Qtreeview.
when one assigns a possibly wrong value to an item, I want the statustip of that item to be set so that hoovering the item shows in the Qstatusbar a hint on why the value is considered wrong.
I use this code:
if not code.is_integer(): 
   self.statuserror(error_top)
   item.setBackground(QBrush(QColorConstants.Red))
   item.setStatusTip(error_top)
   return False 

the self.statuserror code is just a call to self.ui.StatusBar.showMessage(message) with "ERROR: " inserted in the string before showing it)
This works well I get the status tip. However with item.setStatusTip(error_top) I expect that message to show again if I hoover the item. This never happens.
As the item edition is provided by a combobox delegate, I thought that the issue was the delegate being hoovered and not the item. However, if I replace item.setStatusTip(error_top) by item.setToolTip(error_top), hoovering the item does show the tooltip. So why is there a difference?
Is the item missing a reference to the statusBar?
QTreeview and QStatusBar are both child of the same mainwindow .

Please provide a [mre].
